# Inverse-quotes-quine, inverted (pt. 2)

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, quine

Based on a comment by Jo King on my previous question (called '[Inverse-quotes-quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/187163/inverse-quotes-quine)'), I present this new question. The rules are similar, but just, the opposite:

- If your program is run normally, all of the code **not** in the speech marks (`"` - double quotes) should be printed.
- If your program is wrapped in double quotes (in turn inverting the speech marks), the code that is normally n̶o̶t̶ in quotes should be printed.

E.g:

Let's say you have the following code:

```
fancyStuff("myCode"); "I like".isGreat();
```

If I run it, I would expect an output of:

```
fancyStuff(
); 
.isGreat();
```

However, if I wrapped it in quotes, I would get:

```
"fancyStuff("myCode"); "I like".isGreat();"
```

When this code is run, the expected output would be:

```
myCode
I like
```

Obviously, the above example is not a functional response in any language. Your job is to write the code that performs in this way.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes apply.
- The printed values, in both quoted and unquoted forms, must be non-empty, or consist solely of whitespace. This also means that all programs must include at least one set of quotes.
- However, trailing/preceeding whitespace is allowed.
- The quoted and unquoted strings *must* print different results.
- No looking at your own code, required file names, etc.
- Unmatched quotes are disallowed
- If there are multiple strings, they can either be printed as newlines (as in the example), or in some other *human-readable* way - no arrays or objects
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, any answers in that question which print the same string for both raw and wrapped source is also valid to this one.

Comment: @tsh technically correct, but I should probably add a rule against that...

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```python
''*2;print"''*2;print"''*2;print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SqmCroKSkFPNfXV3LyLqgKDOvRAkr8z9QFRdUA4iKttI1jFVQVihKzc0vS1UoKUrMzMnMS1fISy0H0qlcXKkVqckaIJWaEKa6kro2iKsNZGj@BwA)

Based on my [initial solution for the other variant of this puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187168/86422).

Answer (score 3):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>39</s> 16 bytes

```
"l2*0.|or|["090.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XynHSMtArya/qCZaycDSQO//fwA)
([quoted](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0kpx0jLQK8mv6gmWsnA0kBP6f9/AA))

#### Explanation

```
        BA
"l2*0.|or|["090.
"l2*0.|or|["     Pushes the quoted characters onto the stack
            0    Pushes 0
             90. Goes to A
          [      Wipes the stack (requires the 0)
"          "090. Pushes the quoted characters onto the stack
 l2*0.           Length is 4; goes to B
      |or|       Reverses & prints the stack
```

```
A        B
""l2*0.|or|["090."
""                 No-op
  l2*0.            Length is 0; goes to A
 "l2*0.|or|["      Pushes the quoted characters onto the stack
             0     Pushes 0
              90.  Goes to B
       |or|        Reverses & prints the stack
```

### Old answer, 39 bytes

```
"!~l?!<r&[orl&"0[c2*&d0.>o<~~.!?@@0+1fl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0mxLsde0aZILTq/KEdNySA62UhLLcVAzy7fpq5OT9HewcFA2zAt5/9/AA)
([quoted](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0lJsS7HXtGmSC06vyhHTckgOtlISy3FQM8u36auTk/R3sHBQNswLUfp/38A))

Whew, this took a while. Can probably be golfed further.

```
             A
"!~l?!<r&[orl&"0[c2*&d0.>o<~~.!?@@0+1fl
"!~l?!<r&[orl&"                         Pushes the quoted characters onto the stack
               0[                       Wipes the stack
                 c2*&                   Puts 24 into the register (&)
                     d0.                Goes to A
"             "0[c2*&d0.>o<~~.!?@@0+1fl Pushes the quoted characters onto the stack
 !~l?!<                                 No-op (in this case)
       r                                Reverses the stack
        &[                              Wipes the stack, preserving the top &
          o                             Outputs the top character on the stack
           r                            Reverses the stack
            l&                          Puts the current length of the stack into the register
                                        Repeats until &=0, then errors
```

```
                B
""!~l?!<r&[orl&"0[c2*&d0.>o<~~.!?@@0+1fl"
""!~                                      No-op
    l?!<                                  Reverses the IP direction
""!~l?!                                 " No-op
                            ~~.!?@@0+1fl  If the length is 0, go to B
""!~l?!<r&[orl&"                        " Pushes the quoted characters onto the stack (backwards)
                            ~~.!>@@0+1fl  No-op (length != 0)
                         >o<              Outputs all the characters on the stack, then errors
```

*(Note: when I "wipe" the stack, it really creates a new stack; the old stack is still there and accessible)*

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
·"·"·
```

Outputs concatenated without separator.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0HYlMPr/HwA) or [try it online with surrounding quotes](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f6dB2KPr/HwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
         # Program without surrounding quotes will output string "··"
·        # Double the top of the stack, which is empty, so an empty string is pushed
 "·"     # Push string "·" to the stack
    ·    # Double it (2*). Since the legacy version is built in Python, the string is
         # concatenated with itself: "··"
         # (output the top of the stack implicitly as result)

         # Program with surrounding quotes will output string "·"
"·"      # Push string "·" to the stack
   ·     # Double it to string "··"
    "·"  # Push string "·" to the stack
         # (output the top of the stack implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 9 bytes

```
 `H"H` "H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/XyHBQ8kjQUHJ4/9/AA) [Quoted version.](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X0khwUPJI0FByUPp/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 17 bytes

```
"af0.|o<"i!.1!0<9
```

[Try it unquoted!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XykxzUCvJt9GKVNRz1DRwMby/38A) [Quoted!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0kpMc1ArybfRilTUc9Q0cDGUun/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 11 bytes

```
!"!""!$;"$;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19RSVFJSVHFWknF@v9/AA) and [`"!"!""!$;"$;"`](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19JEQiVFFWslYDo/38A)

Just a one-byte 'inversion' of [the prior answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187165/47990) (and 1 byte for having to include the inverting-byte as part of a string literal as well).

#### Explanation

Note that `.` is a NOP command and used as a spacer where other commands are not executed or otherwise removed for explanatory purposes.

`!"` is effectively NOP, resulting in the execution of only `...."!$;"$;` which prints the contents of the code not contained between quote-pairs (`!........$;`)

Wrapping everything in quotes causes the first `!"` to be string literal, resulting in `"!".."!$;"$;.` and which prints the parts of the program contained within quote-pairs (`"!"` and `"!$;"`).